# Python int.to_bytes does not return expected value

Tags: python

I have a problem concerning the conversion from integer to bytes in Python 3.
e.g:

```
a = 31
a.to_bytes(length=1, byteorder="little", signed=False)
```

will result in:

```
b'\x1f'
```

or

```
a = 155
a.to_bytes(length=1, byteorder="little", signed=False)
```

will result in:

```
b'\x9b'
```

So far so good. But e.g. with:

```
a = 46
a.to_bytes(length=1, byteorder="little", signed=False)
```

will result in:

```
b'.'
```

What did I do wrong? Or what is the problem here?

Comment: `assert b'.' == assert b'\x2e'`.

Comment: Get familiar with the [ASCII table](https://www.asciitable.com). 0-31 are invalid characters. Anything over 127 is out of range. Anything in between 32 and 127 is a valid ASCII represented with an hex code. So the bytes in this range are presented as their ASCII values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.` is the ASCII form of 46. You can use `hex()` method to see it:

```
In [38]: b".".hex()
Out[38]: '2e'
```

Answer (score 0):

`b'.'` is correct - it just so happens that the number 46 represents a full stop instead of an invalid character so it is not shown as `b'\x...'`

Answer (score 0):

From 0~31, and 127~255, there are no nice shorter ASCII char for it, therefore it's using the hex string, and from 32~126, each number has a nice ASCII char mapping to it, therefore it prefers to use that shorter ASCII char to represent the byte, instead of the hex value of the number.